# Optimize beginner python script about substring replacement

Tags: python, string, char

I'm tutoring a friend in python, not great at it myself. The assignment is to write a script that reverses some made up alien language in which they repeat every vowel-sequence after adding the letter "p". Some examples:

`tomato -> topomapatopo` `groovy->groopoovy` and `beautiful -> beaupeautipifupul`

The goal is to reverse this. From `groopoovy -> groovy`.

As it is a dutch assignment, there is an exception: "ij" is seen as a vowel. So `blijpij -> blij` (which complicates things a lot, I find)

My solution seems quite bulky to me and I am interested in a better, more elegant solution. As this is an introduction course to programming, basics are key, unfortunately.

```
    word = input()
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
    position = 0
    solution = ""
    while position < len(word):
        if word[position] == 'p':       # obviously, search for the letter 'p'
            add = 1                     # keep track of the sub string size
            group = ""
            while True:                 # loop to get consecutive vowels
                if word[position + add] in vowels:
                    group += word[position + add]
                    if word[position + add] == 'i' and word[position + add + 1] == 'j':   # recognize the "ij"
                        group += 'j'
                        add += 1
                    add += 1
                else:
                    break
                if position+add == len(word):       # stay within the bounds of the string
                    break
            add -= 1
            if word[position - add:position].lower() == group.lower() and group != "":
                position += add
            else:

                solution += 'p'
        else:
            solution += word[position]
        position += 1
    print(solution)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this, for an introductory Python class.
There are several example words at the top; just change the comments #.

Instead of checking for "p" on every step, I check for the beginning of a vowel sequence.  This sequence will always be terminated by "p".  That's the only case where you don't want to append the character to the solution; instead you want to skip to the end of the vowel sequence.

The fact that "ij" is a vowel doesn't create a special case, since "i" begins a vowel sequence.

```
word = "poopoo-poopoo"
# word = "poopooh"
# word = "hijipijinks"
# word = "apapepe"
# word = "copovfepefepe"
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
position = 0
solution = ""
vowel_count = 0   # consecutive vowels
while position < len(word):
    c = word[position]
    if vowel_count > 0:
        if c == 'p':
            position += vowel_count + 1
            vowel_count = 0
            continue
        vowel_count += 1
    else:
        if c in vowels:
            vowel_count = 1
    solution += c
    position += len(c)

print(solution)
```

Comment: This is indeed the more elegant solution I was looking for. Thanks Paul. It needed a small tweak to check the left and right parts when `c=='p'`, otherwise words as 'cape' get busted.

Comment: The program assumes that the input word is formatted according to your recipe and doesn't check it for syntax or spelling errors.  Your version doesn't check that either.  "cape" is not valid input.  "capapepe" *is* valid and correctly gives the result "cape".

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
input_text = "tomato"
encoded = re.sub('([aeiou]+)','\\1p\\1',input_text)
print(encoded)
decoded = re.sub('([aeiou]+)p\\1','\\1',encoded)
print(decoded)
```

should do just that

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was contemplating regex as well, but didn't know how to handle the "ij"-is-a-vowel part. Still can't think of a way for regex to do that..

Comment: @FrankVermeulen Change `[aeiou]` to `(?:[aeiou]|ij)`

Comment: Use a raw string so you don't need to double the backslashes.

Comment: Perfect! It even fits on a single line: `import re;print(re.sub(r'((?:[aeiou]|ij)+)p\1', r'\1', input()))`